# How to make sprites move from one place to another place

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX to create a game but I got a problem:
How to make sprite move from one location marked by click to another location also marked by click? I just need smooth animation.

Here's a code I have already done:
Main application that implements AppListener and InputListener.

```
public class LGame implements ApplicationListener {

public static Field field;
private SpriteBatch bat;
private Listener listener;

@Override
public void create() {
    field = new Field();
    bat = new SpriteBatch();
    listener = new Listener();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(listener);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    bat.begin();
    bat.draw(field.getTexture(), 0, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 31; i++)
        if(!field.getFigure(i).isEaten())
            bat.draw(field.getFigure(i).getTexture(), field.getFigure(i).getPosX()*64, field.getFigure(i).getPosY()*64);
    bat.end();
}
```

"Render" method iterate collection "field" where contained objects on the scene.

```
public class Listener implements InputProcessor {

private int inX;
private int inY;
private int toMove = 32;
private Boolean isWhiteTurn = true;

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    inX = arg0 / 64;
    inY = (512 - arg1) / 64;
    if(toMove == 32){
        if(LGame.field.poll(inX, inY) != 32 && LGame.field.getFigure(LGame.field.poll(inX, inY)).isWhite == isWhiteTurn ){
            toMove = LGame.field.poll(inX, inY);
        }
    }else{
        if(LGame.field.poll(inX, inY) != 32){
            if(LGame.field.getFigure(toMove).isMoveRight(inX, inY)){
                LGame.field.eatFigure(LGame.field.poll(inX, inY));
                LGame.field.setFigurePos(inX, inY, toMove);
                isWhiteTurn = !isWhiteTurn;
                toMove = 32;
            }else{
                toMove = 32;
            }
        }else{
            if(LGame.field.getFigure(toMove).isMoveRight(inX, inY)){
                LGame.field.setFigurePos(inX, inY, toMove);
                isWhiteTurn = !isWhiteTurn;
                toMove = 32;
            }else{
                toMove = 32;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

"touchDown" method is called when the mouse clicked; I have already done changing the position of object, but I need to animate this changing.

Comment: Hi, Could you expand your question a little? Include any code you may have tried thus far formatting in a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [universal tween engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/)

it can be used to create smooth easing between any variable(s). So movement animation, fading, scaling or anything you can think of.